# Twitter ads api. Error:- [{'code': 'INVALID_PARAMETER', 'message': 'Expected GeoId, got "JP" for country', 'parameter': 'country'}]>

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to segment twitter ads data on the basis of `CITIES` set as `segmentation_type` but I don't know the format in which country parameter(required) is to be given.

I tried country codes like `US` and `JP` and got the error.

```
[{
  'code': 'INVALID_PARAMETER', 
  'message': 'Expected GeoId, got "JP" for country', 
  'parameter': 'country'
}]>
```

Have anyone else faced similar issue before? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe your application needs to look up the identifier  rather than use the two letter country code. https://twittercommunity.com/t/help-with-postal-codes-segment/127314

Comment: Thanks for pointing out in the right direction.

Comment: Do you have an simple example? Can you add it to your post?

Comment: Are you facing same issue. Above link shared by osowskit really helps. You have to first get targeting value of country and use that as parameter.